# Сохранение данных QTableView при закрытии приложения с использованием QSettings

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt, qsettings

Изъезженный вопрос но тем не менее до сих пор не могу понять как сохранить данные после закрытия. Использую `QtCore.QSettings()`. Написал часть кода для сохранения, не работает.

- сюда же отдельный вопрос как расширить колоны в таблице в коде?

**Counter.py**

```
import sys
from random import randint
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class CustomTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomTableView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)

    def KeyPressEvent(self, event: QtGui.QKeyEvent):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter:
            print("Key_Enter ")
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            print("Key_Return ")

class NumberSortModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):

    def lessThan(self, left_index: "QModelIndex",
                 right_index: "QModelIndex") -> bool:

        left_var: str = left_index.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        right_var: str = right_index.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

        try:
            return float(left_var) < float(right_var)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass

        try:
            return left_var < right_var
        except TypeError: 
            return True

class Counter(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Counter, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        font = QtGui.QFont("Formula1", 10, QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        self.setFont(font)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Name" , "Points"])

        self.proxy = NumberSortModel()
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)

        self.table = CustomTableView(self)
        self.table.setModel(self.proxy)

        update_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Update")                           
        update_button.clicked.connect(self.on_update_button)   
        update_action = QtWidgets.QAction()
        sort_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Sort")

        self.qlineedit_name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.qlineedit_name.resize(24, 80)
        self.qlineedit_name.selectAll()
        self.qlineedit_points = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.qlineedit_points.resize(24, 80)
        self.qlineedit_points.selectAll()

        horisontal_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        horisontal_layout.addWidget(self.qlineedit_name, stretch=1)
        horisontal_layout.addWidget(self.qlineedit_points, stretch=1)
        horisontal_layout.addStretch(1)
        horisontal_layout.addWidget(update_button)                                 
        horisontal_layout.addWidget(sort_button)
        horisontal_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        grid_layout.addLayout(horisontal_layout, 0, 0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.table, 1, 0)

        #---------------------------------------------------------------------
        # settings = QtCore.QSettings('table.list', QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
        # settings.setValue(self.table)
        # settings.sync()
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------

    def on_update_button(self, event):
        name = self.qlineedit_name.text().strip()
        point = self.qlineedit_points.text().strip() if self.qlineedit_points.text().strip() else '0'
        if not point.isdigit():
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'ВНИМАНИЕ', 'Заполните правильно поле ввода Points!')
            return

        if not name:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'ВНИМАНИЕ', 'Заполните поле ввода Name!')
            return
        rows  = self.table.model().rowCount()
        add_record = True
        for row in range(rows):
            if name == self.proxy.data(self.proxy.index(row, 0)):
                add_record = False
                row_edit = row
                break

        if add_record:  
            if self.table.selectedIndexes(): 
                row = self.table.selectedIndexes()[-1].row()
                self.model.insertRow(row+1, [QtGui.QStandardItem(name), 
                                    QtGui.QStandardItem(point)])                  

            else:
                self.model.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem(name), 
                                        QtGui.QStandardItem(point)])            
        else:  
            self.model.setData(self.model.index(row_edit, 1), point, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = Counter()
    window.setWindowTitle("Counter")
    window.setMinimumSize(480, 380)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Comment: я посмотрел что пишут по аналогичной тематике. 
Попался только один пост, который должен вам помочь.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61959920/pyqt-save-and-restore-dynamically-added-tabs-with-different-types-of-widgets-u

Реализация проекта здесь https://github.com/David52920/QSettings 
 
Обратите внимание на `class SettingsManager`, функцию `def settingsContext(...)`, 
методы: `def closeEvent`; `def read_settings`, `def write_settings`, 
и вызов `self.read_settings()`.

Comment: Проект рабочий, только чтобы сделать восстановление после повторного входа 
мне понадобилось дважды нажать кнопку `Subwindow` панели инструментов главного окна.

Comment: в классе SettingsManager 200 строк. Что конкретно мне там надо?

Comment: 1. Проект, на который я вас отослал, у вас работает ? 2. 200 строк это не много. 3. Вы должны понимать каждую строку. 4. Вам надо то, что касается `QTableView`

Comment: 1. Проект который вы отсолали ругается на 5 необъявленных переменных которые я не знаю как объявить (по типу ```self.TabNumber = number```). 2. 200 строк для меня много поскольку я новичек и не способен быстро осозновать код. 3. Пытаюсь.

Comment: 1. вам надо скопировать ТРИ модуля в какую либо папку и запустить `Test_MDI.py`. 2. Торопиться никуда не надо. Изучайте вдумчиво каждую строку.

Comment: а возможно ли просто сделать кнопку или хоткей ctrl + s для сохранения в файл?

Comment: запустил код. работает. поменял некоторые значения и поставил свои вкладки. НЕ сохранилось... может проблема не в коде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, если взять горизонтальный хедер, и нам надо растянуть колонки на всю ширину таблицы (метод [QHeaderView.setSectionResizeMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode)):

```
tableView.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

остальные флаги [тут](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#ResizeMode-enum)

или, если для конкретной колонки, то так:

```
tableView.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(column, QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

Что касается сохранения после закрытия, например главного окна приложения, то надо перегрузить метод [`closeEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#closeEvent) у закрываемого окна:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings('sets.ini', QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue("key", "Value")
```

чтения и другая информация в [документации](https://docs.huihoo.com/pyqt/PyQt5/pyqt_qsettings.html)

Сохранение настроек в конструкторе главного окна (проверено - работает!):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings

def Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None)
        settings = QSettings('sets.ini', QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue("Key", "Value")
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109026/discussion-on-answer-by-alexander-chernin-----).